# Preciso fazer requisições para o php via $_POST com a utilização do Keyup - Função do teclado

Tags: php, jquery, matriz, requisição, keyup

primeira vez escrevendo aqui no site :) . Minha dúvida envolve jQuery e PHP. Preciso fazer uma requisição para o arquivo .php . Dessa maneira :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E no arquivo .PHP preciso comparar se parte do texto que digitei existe na matriz[]. Por exemplo :
Texto digitado : rroz - na Matriz[0] temos o arroz, que condiz com o texto digitado :
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -2):

Opa, é minha primeira resposta aqui também.
já que está usando Jquery, você pode usar o ajax para fazer a requisição

Js:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "BuscarLista.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: "pDigitado=rroz",
    dataType: "html"

    }).done(function(resposta) {
        console.log(resposta);
```

No php, pode percorrer a lista usando foreach e checando se cada elemento da lista
tem o valor.

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    $valorDigitado = $_POST['pDigitado'];
}

$arrayItens = ['arroz', 'feijão', 'carne', 'salada'];

foreach($arrayItens as $item) {
    if(preg_match("/{$valorDigitado}/", $item)) {
       echo 'Tem esse valor';
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thalles, cara ... você ajudou muito, funcionou sua lógica lá no php. Acabei utilizando o post , mas funcionou da mesma forma . Valeu !